# Replacing spaces in comma separated string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Friends, I need some help..
I have a comma separated string in SQL in which I want to replace spaces between the commas.

I am using the following statement, but it's not working as expected

```
REPLACE(replace(@code,' ,',','),', ',',')
```

space before the comma is getting replaced with comma, but not the space after the comma.

Comment: Can we have some sample `@code` you are using, please?

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one space symbol between commas?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(@code,' ,',','),', ',',')
```

I'm suggesting this because the replace statement is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @code varchar(50)=', this ,is a ,    test, '
while(PATINDEX ('% ,%',@code)>0 or PATINDEX ('%, %',@code)>0 )
select @code=REPLACE(replace(@code,' ,',','),', ',',')
select @code
```